# Most compact way to represent a 32-bit integer in a csv-file

Tags: compression

I have a lot of (unsigned) integers originating from a measurement. Those are stored in a csv Textfile:

```
1111492765
562352
5362346
...
```

Since I have to transmitt this file through a low-bandwidth connection I am looking for a way to save storage-space (chars).

What is the best way to do so beside using a compression (gzip, ...)?

So far representing the 32-bit integers as hexvalues seems promising:

```
1111492765 = 10 Byte
```

is the same as

```
4240089D = 8 Byte
```

Note: At the receiving part of the Transmission I can convert the file to anything I like.

Answer (score 2):

Following your integer -> hex (base 16) idea, you can convert the numbers to [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) - this way, you'll only need `ceil(log(number value)/log(64))` characters, e.g:

```
ceil(log(1111492765)/log(64)) = ceil(5.008) = 6 characters
ceil(log(562352)/log(64)) = ceil(3.184) = 4 characters
```

For this, you'll have to convert the number value by repeatingly doing "modulo 64" followed by "divide with 64". This way, you'll get values in the range 0..63 that you can encode using a Base64 alphabet (e.g. `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`). On the receiving code you can recombine the characters to get the original value.

Example for "562352":

```
Encoding:
---------
562352 mod 64 = 48 => encode as "w"
floor(562352/64) = 8786
8786 mod 64 = 18 => encode as "S"
floor(8786/64) = 137
137 mod 64 = 9 => encode as "J"
floor(137/64) = 2
2 mod 64 = 2 => encode as "B"
Number is below 64 => finished

Decoding:
---------
wSJB = 48, 18, 9, 2
value = 48 + 18 * (64 ^ 1) + 9 * (64 ^ 2) + 2 * (64 ^ 3) = 562352
```

Depending on how many valid characters you can find for csv, you can extend the alphabet to get shorter encodings (e.g there's [Ascii85/Base85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)).

Also note: If a subset of your values are very similar to each other (not the case in your example, but might be the case for the real measured values), you can additionally use delta compression by only encoding the difference between two values.